# MS SQL show result biger with sum

Tags: sql-server

I got table That looks like the following:

```
NAME        VALUE
stock1      -1
stock1       5
stock1      -2
stock2      10
stock2      -2
stock2      -1
stock3      15
stock4      16
stock4      -5
stock4      -6
```

and Have have written the below SQL statement,

```
select 
x.name, x.SUM(value) 
from tabelex x

join tabeley y on x.id = y.id

where y.location like = ENG
```

What I would like to know is, how do I make it show result > 1

Comment: Have a look at [SELECT - HAVING (Transct-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If What you need is to display only the values where SUM(value)  is greater than 1, then Just add a having and a Group by :

```
select 
x.name, SUM(x.value) 
from tabelex x

join tabeley y on x.id = y.id

where y.location like 'ENG'
group by x.name -- Added
having SUM(x.value) >1 -- Added
```

You can't use Aggregates for some column without using Group By, You either need to use the Aggregate for all columns without Group by of if you want to use it only for few columns then Group By is Must